# How to get the downloading time of a file from server side to Client side - Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, server-side

I make the request from client side aspx page and able to download a file in server side. It takes around 6 to 15 sec randomly. Once the file download is completed, i want to send time log to client side from asp server page. how can i send the time or message back to client side indicating the download has completed in particular timing ?

Comment: You could simply populate a textbox or label with the time data. As far as timing, take a look at https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c-sharp+timing+file+download play with it and if you have any problems, show us your code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I'cant tell you exact solution but for example like that (server involved solution):

1. Implement server action that returns download time by download id.
   Let's say domain.ext/getdownloadtime?id=39994884
2. When download is requested from client, store download identity
   inside user session on the server (this should be implemented as List if user can have multiple downloads at time).
3. When download is finished on clients side request server action (getdownloadtime) with id according to recently finished download. You can do it with javascript background request. When server returns download time just display it as you want.